# Does google stopped map api v1?

Tags: android

google map API v1 is not working..
Does Google Stopped their service for map API v1
Because i cant see any map in my application, Instead i can only see some grids.

Comment: It is advisable to shift to the V2 and there are new features on it. :)

Comment: Correct, although it's worth noting that v2 will not work on devices which don't support `Google Play Services`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it has not stopped. Google maps v1 however has been deprecated. If you have a api key you should be able to still use it (I've just noticed you can still request new keys for the next few days). You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/):

> Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API as been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 3rd, 2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this version. No new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1. However, apps using v1 will continue to work on devices. Existing and new developers are encouraged to use Google Maps Android API v2.

Regarding your problem, are you trying it on a device or on the emulator. Also, does said device/emulator have a connection? Try on the browser.